# "office hours" with jodatime, how store in database

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, hibernate-mapping, jodatime

I'm looking into storing a set of "working/office hours" for each day of the week, i.e.
mon - 9 to 5
tue - 8.30 to 16.30
...
sat 10.00 to 14.00
etc.

Using Jodatime in the service layer, I'm going to use these values to calculate which parts of certain Intervals that fall within and without these office hours.

The best way to calculate that seems to me to be by using the interval's Overlap-function, as this speedily put together example shows:

```
    LocalTime startOfficeHours = new LocalTime(9, 30);
    LocalTime endOfficeHours = new LocalTime(17, 30);
    Interval officeHoursToday = new Interval(startOfficeHours.toDateTimeToday(), endOfficeHours.toDateTimeToday());

    DateTime start = new DateTime().withHourOfDay(8).withMinuteOfHour(30);
    DateTime end = start.plusHours(7).plusMinutes(45);

    Interval workShift = new Interval(start, end);

    Period withinOfficeHours = officeHoursToday.overlap(workShift).toPeriod();

    assertEquals(withinOfficeHours.getHours(), 6);
    assertEquals(withinOfficeHours.getMinutes(), 45);
```

Now, i need to find a way to read and write those office hours intervals to and from the database in a speedy fashion...

If i just use integers, that'd be 28 columns - but that might be quicker than writing and reading PersistentLocalTimes that might contain a lot of redundant info. But in both those cases i'd end up having to create intervals manually all the time.

Is there a way to store a "date-agnostic" interval in the database that i then can change the date for when i make my calculations as per above?

if anybody's been through this and has any pointers, i'd be much obliged.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the two values `workShift.getStartMillis()` and  `workShift.getEndillis()`  (which return  `long` in Java) to your database as two fields of type `big int`.

You could save the two values as a `;` separated text field if you want to separate them in your code later.

You could also store `workShift.toDurationMillis()` in the database as `big int` if you want to apply the addition of that number of milliseconds yourself later rather than creating a Joda Time `Interval` (since there is no constructor that takes the duration as `long`).